# Do high-efficiency furnaces work well in older homes with restrictive ducting?

Tags: heating, furnace

I was told that a high efficiency furnace needs a certain amount of airflow to work properly. And that in an older home if you don't have enough duct work that a high efficiency furnace is actually a bad idea.  Do others agree with that?

Comment: Bad in what sense? Efficiency? Comfort? Fan durability?

Comment: I would disagree some units do have multi speed fans but if your original system was sized correctly the newer units in many cases be a lower BTU rating because they have better heat exchangers than older systems.

Answer (score 1):

If by airflow you mean the flow of heated air through your home, then I would say yes: a furnace needs to be sized based on how much heated air can be pumped through your home. If your furnace is enormous, and your ducts are small enough that the total air flow is too low, then the furnace won't be able to transfer enough heat to the home air, producing too-hot output air while reducing the furnace's efficiency.

However, this does NOT mean that no high-efficiency furnace will work with an older home with few/narrow heating ducts. You just have to find one that's appropriately sized.

A side note: furnace installers have a tendency to over-size furnaces and boilers, on the theory that too big is better than too small. The truth is that many (most?) furnaces and boilers are larger than they need to be. So, get a heat loss calculation done for your home and then proceed from there.